# How to archive an org-mode subtree along with its parent headlines

Tags: org-mode

Let me start out by saying I've seen various attempts to address questions similar to mine, but none of them handle the things I'm looking for.  Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

Say I start with an org-file that looks like:

```
#+ARCHIVE: ::* Archived

* Foo
  * Tasks
    * Task1
  * Thoughts
    * Thought1
    * Thought2

* Archived
```

Now I put the point (i.e. cursor) on *Thought1* and run `org-super-archive` (the magical command I'm hoping to find).  The result should be:

```
#+ARCHIVE: ::* Archived

* Foo
  * Tasks
    * Task1
  * Thoughts
    * Thought2

* Archived
  * Foo
    * Thoughts
      * Thought1
```

Now I move the point to *Thought2* and again run `org-super-archive`, which should give me:

```
#+ARCHIVE: ::* Archived

* Foo
  * Tasks
    * Task1
  * Thoughts

* Archived
  * Foo
    * Thoughts
      * Thought1
      * Thought2
```

So the basic operation I'm seeking is the ability to archive a subtree to whatever target location is specified with `#+ARCHIVE` (or `org-archive-location`) **where (1) the full path of the archived subtree is mirrored beneath that target location, and (2) the subtree will be merged into an existing path under the target if an appropriate path already exists**.

As an added bonus, it would be nice if it were possible to choose whether or not the "full path" of a subtree to be archived will include the org-file name as the root of the path.  This would be useful in cases where you archive from multiple org-files to a single `archive.org` file.

Comment: Have you tried using properties under each heading ? it works for me. See [Keeping the context when archiving in Emacs org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143959/keeping-the-context-when-archiving-in-emacs-org-mode)